# just some fields post from my html through my register.php to my email

Tags: php, html, email

I can’t seem to get the additional fields in my html to post through my register.php file

this is what I get in my email: It only is posting the email address and not the other fields name,surname,phone,and insurance.

First Name: (not showing up)
Last Name:  (not showing up)
E-mail: myemail@myemail.com ( only field showing up)
Phone:      (not showing up)
Insurance:  (not showing up)

Can anyone help me with what i am overlooking?

`<form role="form" action="register.php" method="post" enctype="plain"> <input` `name="email" class="subscribe-input" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address..."` `required="yes" type="email script type="text/javascript">,<input name="name"` `class="subscribe2-input" placeholder="First Name" required="yes" type="email` `script type="text/javascript">,<input name="surname" class="subscribe3-input"` `placeholder="Last Name" required="yes" type="email script`type="text/javascript">,`<input name="phone" class="subscribe4-input"` `placeholder="Phone" required="yes" type="email script`type="text/javascript">,`<input name="insurance" class="subscribe5-input"` `placeholder="Do You Have A Life License" required="yes" type="email script` `type="text/javascript"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-download subscribe-submit"` `type="submit">Learn More</button><script type="text/javascript">`

```
<?php
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_surname = $_POST['surname'];
$field_phone = $_POST['phone'];
$field_insurance = $_POST['insurance'];

$mail_to = 'info@teamworktowealth.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_email;

$body_message = 'First Name: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Last Name: '.$field_surname."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Insurance: '.$field_insurance."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">;
  window.location.href ='http://www.thankyou.fidelisinsurancecompany.com';
 </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  alert('Registration failed. Please, send an email to info@fidelisltd.com');
  window.location = 'http://www.fidelisinsurancecompany.com';
 </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: at the top of your php temporarily add a `print_r($_POST); exit;` to see what your POST array looks like

Comment: format your code so its readable, if you want people to read it

Comment: from the looks of your form fields, they are not created correctly. You're not closing your input tags and starting new ones for your additional input fields.

Comment: I tried adding print_r($_POST); above the <?php and right below it and nothing changed

Comment: I also tried closing the input fields like this:   <form role="form" action="register.php" method="post" enctype="plain"> <input name="email" class="subscribe-input" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address..." required="yes" type="email script type="text/javascript">,  I did tis between each field and it still wouldn't post

Comment: The fields show up on the web page and everything works except the additional data on 4 of the fields are not showing up. This is what it looks like in my in-box First Name: 
Last Name: 
E-mail: max@...
Phone: 
Insurance:

Comment: @Max Share the html you are using as it is;

Answer (score 0):

At least separate the design from the logic, as much as possible.

**register_process.php**

```
<?php

if (count($_POST)) {

    $field_email = $_POST['email'];
    $field_name = $_POST['name'];
    $field_surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $field_phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $field_insurance = $_POST['insurance'];

    $mail_to = 'info@teamworktowealth.com';
    $subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_email;

    $body_message = 'First Name: '.$field_name."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Last Name: '.$field_surname."\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Insurance: '.$field_insurance."\n";

    $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

}
```

**register.php**

```
<?php include 'register_process.php'; ?>
<html>
    <body>

    <!-- all your form elements go here -->

    <?php if (count($_POST)): ?>
        <?php if ($mail_status): ?>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
               window.location.href ='http://www.thankyou.fidelisinsurancecompany.com';
            </script>
        <?php else: ?>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                alert('Registration failed. Please, send an email to info@fidelisltd.com');
                window.location = 'http://www.fidelisinsurancecompany.com';
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seriously need to format your code and make it readable. Had to copy it out to see the issue. This is your current form inputs

```
<input name="email" class="subscribe-input" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address..." required="yes" type="email script type="text/javascript",input name="name" class="subscribe2-input" placeholder="First Name" required="yes" type="email script type="text/javascript",input name="surname" class="subscribe3-input" placeholder="Last Name" required="yes" type="email script type="text/javascript",input name="phone" class="subscribe4-input" placeholder="Phone" required="yes" type="email script type="text/javascript",input name="insurance" class="subscribe5-input" placeholder="Do You Have A Life License" required="yes" type="email script type="text/javascript"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-download subscribe-submit" type="submit">Learn More</button>
```

You are missing a lot of closing quotes and closing tags. Here is a fix

```
<input name="email" class="subscribe-input" placeholder="Enter your e-mail address..." required="yes" type="email">
<input name="name" class="subscribe2-input" placeholder="First Name" required="yes" type="text">
<input name="surname" class="subscribe3-input" placeholder="Last Name" required="yes" type="text">
<input name="phone" class="subscribe4-input" placeholder="Phone" required="yes" type="text">
<input name="insurance" class="subscribe5-input" placeholder="Do You Have A Life License" required="yes" type="text">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-download subscribe-submit" type="submit">Learn More</button>
```

Your codes need a fix of their own as well... seperate logic from view as much as you can, close your quotes and tags.

Comment: Thank you very much and I apologize for the formatting. This worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to see it worked @Max Dont forget to select it as the answer.. good luck